# scaling a UIView without scaling any of the subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

i have a container view that contains another smaller view inside
i want to scale the container view without the other view being affected
i am using just a longGestureRecognizer to detect the long hold
then using UIView.animate(withDuration:1) {} and using CGAffineTransform to scale the view up
here's is the code for both of the views
'''

```
  let viewIWantToScale = UIView()
  let viewIDontWantToScale = UIView()

  private func configureViewIWantToScale() {
    let tabDetector = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gestureAction(_:)))
    viewIWantToScale.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    viewIWantToScale.addGestureRecognizer(tabDetector)
    viewIWantToScale.autoresizesSubviews = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    
        viewIWantToScale.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        viewIWantToScale.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        viewIWantToScale.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
        viewIWantToScale.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
        
    ])
    
    viewIWantToScale.backgroundColor = .blue
    
}

private func configureViewIDontWantToScale() {
    viewIDontWantToScale.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    viewIDontWantToScale.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    
        viewIDontWantToScale.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewIWantToScale.centerYAnchor),
        viewIDontWantToScale.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewIWantToScale.centerXAnchor),
        viewIDontWantToScale.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
        viewIDontWantToScale.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
        
    ])
    
    viewIDontWantToScale.backgroundColor = .red
    
}
```

'''

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you should be able to do it with by settng the constraints on the non-scaling view to constants, while using relaitve values for the one you want to scale (eg. set it width equal to its superview's width, with a multiplier of 0.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inverted()` function of `CGAffineTransform`.
Add this line just after transforming your `viewIWantToScale.transform` line:

```
self.viewIDontWantToScale.transform = TRANSFORM_YOU_USED.inverted()
```